# How to print stringgrid to Rave report in Delphi

Tags: delphi, rave-reports

How to print the content of a stringgrid using Rave report in Delphi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the help provided by Nevrona is very good.

As a general idea:

1) you fill a clientdataset with the data from the string grid.
 
2) set the rvproject, rvsystem, rvdatasetconnection components
3) create the rave report, create the data view and connect it to the rvdatasetconnection 
4) put a region on the report
5) in the region put a databand
 
6) on the databand put datatext components for each column from the dataview
7) link all the datatext components to the dataview elements

or you can create the report dynamic.

best regards,

 Radu

Comment: +1, can you give an example of the stringgrid printing with Rave report? as im new and cant understand the answer